# Windows 10: How to edit what shows up in Quick Access

Tags: windows, windows-10

How can I define the items that will show up in "Quick Access"? I have "Remove from Quick Access" an item, then another item shows up in QA. I just want to define that "these three items should appear in QA, nothing else."

Comment: You cannot just define the list.  Clear Quick Access and then use the 3 things. They will go on the list but others will be added later.   See if this helps.   https://www.simplehow.tips/a/17/how-to-customize-or-disable-quick-access-in-windows10

Comment: I don't have anything in Quick Access that I haven't pinned there myself. Your additional entries might be added by some installed software. Which entries were added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any method that does the "nothing else" part, but you can pin folders to the Quick Access list so that it is easy to distinguish the ones you want there from ones that are automatically added.

Either drag a folder onto where it says "Quick access" (you can position the item in the list, but watch out for if it decides to copy/move instead), or right-click on the folder and choose "Pin to Quick access" (the safer method).

To un-pin a folder, right-click on it in the "Quick access" list and choose "Unpin from Quick access".

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable frequent folders. Here's how to do it.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/pin-remove-and-customize-in-quick-access-7344ff13-bdf4-9f40-7f76-0b1092d2495b

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1219208)